# Which characters are dead in the MCU as of Guardians of the Galaxy 2?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification

***Needless to say, this question includes major spoilers for the MCU.***

---

In the Marvel Cinematic Universe, multiple characters have supposedly *died*, only to be brought back later in future films.

- **Loki** (2011 - 2012): Falls into a black hole in *Thor's* finale only to [somehow](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/17910/79413) survive and serve as the primary antagonist for *The Avengers*.
- **Bucky Barnes** (2011 - 2014): Plummets off a HYDRA train in *Captain America: The First Avenger* before returning as the titular Winter Soldier in *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*.
- **Agent Coulson** (2012 - 2013): Killed by Loki in *The Avengers* before [recovering in Tahiti](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Resurrection_of_Phil_Coulson) for *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*
- **Nick Fury** (2014 - 2015): Supposedly died via gunshot wound in *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* before reappearing in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* after faking his own death.

With all these deaths and revivals, it's hard to keep track of which characters are actually dead anymore.

**Which characters are currently dead in the Marvel Cinematic Universe as of Guardians of the Galaxy 2?**

To clarify, I'm not asking about which characters may or may not be revived for future films. Instead, I'm asking which characters are ***currently*** presumed to be dead in the MCU based on the films that have released.

Comment: Marvel make good films, but they need to suck it up and actually kill a hero permanently.

Comment: It's a truth universally acknowledged that the only character in the Marvel Universe who's permanently dead is Uncle Ben.

Comment: To what level of detail? Start adding in even just named thugs and baddies, and this gets pretty long thanks to AoS.

Comment: As your question demonstrates, nobody is permanently dead.

Comment: @RDFozz I think some of the Agents of Shield characters were added in edits after GotG2 came out. You may want to do a revert.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro - It looked like the only changes that went in with the Avengers Infinity War data were adding the names of a couple of characters, and removing the Coulson/Ghost Rider note (which someone had commented probably shouldn't have been there). I think it's good, but someone else is welcome to update if I did screw something up.

Comment: Nick Fury's survival was confirmed in *The Winter Soldier*; he talks to Cap and Falcon at his (fake) grave at the end of the movie.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming you mean good guys and not all characters (which would include numerous villain deaths).

- Agent Peggy Carter - Captain America: Civil War
- Frigga (Thor's mother) - Thor: The Dark World
- Meredith Quill - Guardians of the Galaxy
- Yondu - Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2
- Howard Stark - Captain America: Civil War
- Maria Stark - Captain America: Civil War
- The Ancient One - Doctor Strange
- T'Chaka - Captain America: Civil War
- Pietro Maximoff - Avengers: Age of Ultron
- Original Groot (I think it can be argued that the new Groot, who doesn't seem to have any memories from his past life, is a new version of Groot) - Guardians of the Galaxy

And if we are going into the land of Agents of Shield and Agent Carter

- Trip
- YoYo's cousin
- Simmon's space boyfriend
- Coulson's girlfriend
- Daisy's electric boogaloo (Lincoln)
- Definitely not-Adama Adama /  Robert Gonzalez
- Patton Oswalt clone #2
- Victoria Hand
- Director Mace
- Xena warrior princess (Lucy Lawless) /  Isabelle Hartley
- Jason Wilkes - Agent Carter
- Framework Ward
- Framework Trip
- Framework Hope

*I tried to only include characters which had appeared in more than one episode.*

Comment: Pietro Maximoff (Quicksilver) - killed by Ultron in Avengers: Age of Ultron

Comment: Coulson shouldn't be on the list.  It was a tease that might or might not pay off, be averted, etc.  Besides, technically we're all living on borrowed time and eventually death will come for us.

Comment: Is Hartley and her driver on the list? I didn't see them. Also Major Gonzalos.

Comment: "xena" = isabelle hartley. "definitely not-adama adama" = robert gonzalez

Comment: Vision was killed by Wanda and Thanos and I don't think he was brought back again (except for WandaVision).

Comment: @JavaMikeMoore The question specifically says " as of Guardians of the Galaxy 2"