# How many named characters died in Avengers: Infinity War?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

How many named characters have died

> and/or disintegrated

by the end of *Avengers: Infinity War*. It is difficult to speculate who died on

> Xandar and the Asgardian ship.

So restrict it to on-screen deaths only.

Comment: Similar question from mvoies.se [Avengers Infinity War: Casualty List?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88611/avengers-infinity-war-casualty-list)

Comment: Related: [Which characters are currently dead in the Marvel Cinematic Universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/162530/79413)

Comment: Oh, probably about half of the named characters, one would think :-).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

According to [this video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a20iZNp9EMg) and [this article from Time](http://time.com/5252990/avengers-infinity-war-deaths/):

> **Killed by "traditional" methods**
>  - Gamora
>  - Heimdall
>  - Loki
>  - Vision
>
>  **Disintegrated by Thanos**
>  - Bucky Barnes
>  - Drax
>  - Groot
>  - Mantis
>  - Maria Hill
>  - Nick Fury
>  - Peter Parker (Spider-Man)
>  - Peter Quill (Star-Lord)
>  - Sam Wilson (Falcon)
>  - Stephen Strange (Doctor Strange)
>  - T'Challa (Black Panther)
>  - Wanda Maximoff (Scarlet Witch)

Not included in the video, but also named characters who died:

> **Thanos's Black Order**
>  - Corvus Glaive
>  - Cull Obsidian
>  - Ebony Maw
>  - Proxima Midnight

Named in the film, but their fate is unknown at the end of the movie:

> - Clint Barton (Hawkeye); mentioned by Black Widow but does not appear
>  - Eitri; last seen at the forges of Nidavellir
>  - Johann Schmidt (Red Skull/Stonekeeper); last seen on Vormir
>  - Ned Leeds; last seen on a school bus driven by Stan Lee
>  - Pepper Potts; last heard from via Tony's headset
>  - Scott Lang (Ant-Man); mentioned by Black Widow but does not appear
>  - Shuri; last seen in her lab attempting to remove the Mind Stone from Vision
>  - Taneleer Tivan (The Collector); appears but only as an illusion
>  - Thaddeus Ross (Secretary of State); last seen via hologram conference call
>  - Wong; last seen returning to his post at the Sanctum Santorum

---

Not in the movie, but confirmed status by [Word of God](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WordOfGod) from the Russos ([via Huffington Post](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/avengers-infinity-war-directors-confirm-which-characters-died-off-screen_us_5af5f6fee4b032b10bfaa3a0)):

Alive:

> - Aunt May
>  - Howard the Duck

Dead:

> - Betty Ross
>  - Lady Sif
>  - Unnamed Asgardian Actor (Matt Damon)

Unknown:

> - Jane Foster (Updated: Alive!)
>  - Korg
>  - Miek
>  - Nakia

---

Also not in the movie, but fate… slightly clarified by the Russos [(via Gizmodo)](https://io9.gizmodo.com/joe-russo-gave-the-infinity-war-answers-youve-been-wait-1825776831):

> - Valkyrie is confirmed to have survived the initial attack on the Asgardian ship, but no status was given as to whether she survived the Infinity Gauntlet.

---

And, **completely breaking** with the "named characters in *Avengers: Infinity War*" theme of the question, [via Uproxx](https://uproxx.com/movies/russo-brothers-avengers-4/):

> **This character wasn’t in the movie, but I’m wondering if the *Galaga* guy from the first *Avengers* survived Thanos’ snap or not?**
>  *Joe Russo*: He got snapped in the middle of a *Galaga* game. He was seconds away from his all-time high score.
>  **I’m considering this canon.**
>  *Joe Russo*: He’s gone.

---

Killed by the events of *Avengers: Infinity War*, but not shown until *Ant-Man and the Wasp*:

> - Hank Pym
>  - Janet van Dyne (The Wasp)
>  - Hope van Dyne

…and shown to survive:

> - Scott Lang (Ant-Man), although he appears to be stranded in the Quantum Realm.

---

Revealed to have survived in the book *Avengers: Infinity War: The Cosmic Quest Volume Two: Aftermath* [(via CBR.com)](https://www.cbr.com/jane-foster-survived-infinity-war):

> - Doctor Erik Selvig
>  - Darcy Lewis
>  - Jane Foster

Comment: I would also add "Mentioned in the film, but their fate is unknown at the end of the movie" and include Ant-Man and Hawkeye.

Comment: @Lefteris008: Done, along with last known status for the "fate unknown" characters.

Comment: @Arclite you should add to the list those Asgardians who we knew were on the ship because we saw them there at the end of Thor:Ragnarok, which occurred just moments before the ship was attacked in Infinity War .  Like Valkyrie for example.  Possibly fate unknown, but more likely to be on the dead list.

Comment: @JK.The questioner explicitly asks to leave these characters out; as they are neither named nor appear in the movie, I don't think it's worth including them. Given that Thanos is big on evenly halving things, I'm holding out hope they survived somehow. :)

Comment: Ned, Parker's friend is also left unknown but I guess he's not that important...

Comment: "There's an Ant-Man *and* Spider-Man?". I think at least one of them is dead ;)

Comment: In an interview, the Russos said that Valkyrie and a bunch of other Asgardians survived in escape pods. We don't know who else may have died besides the ones we specifically see on screen.

Comment: @Darjeeling Damn, how could I forget Ned? Added.

Comment: So of all these beloved characters who died, *Howard the Duck* manages to live through it. Beautiful.

Comment: @SydneySleeper No character is more beloved than Howard the Duck. All joking aside, I would love for him to randomly show up in a final ultimate battle in Avengers 4.

Comment: worth adding that a post-credits scene in Ant-man and the Wasp confirms Lang survived the snap

Comment: Whoops. I'd added who was shown to have died in that scene, but not who was shown to have lived. Fixed.

Answer (score 7):

Asgardian ship:

> - Loki
>  - Heimdall

Vormir:

> - Gamora

Space:

> - Ebony Maw

Knowhere:

> - The Collector

Titan:

> - Mantis
>  - Star-Lord
>  - Drax
>  - Doctor Strange
>  - Spider-Man

Wakanda:

> - Vision
>  - Scarlet Witch
>  - Bucky Barnes
>  - Groot
>  - Falcon
>  - T'Challa
>  - Proxima Midnight
>  - Cull Obsidian
>  - Corvus Glaive

Unknown Earth:

> - Maria Hill
>  - Nick Fury

Comment: I'm curious about one of the characters on your list. I won't say which one, because there's no spoiler tags in comments; it's the first character in my 'fate unknown' list. Is this character actually dead? They were shown on-screen, but it was revealed to be a ruse. Were they ever actually confirmed dead?

Comment: Fair, but we see that place to have been decimated and thanos now possesses the stone. My inclination is that he was sort of replaying the events from earlier.

Comment: Very short list.

Answer (score 2):

The release of *Ant-Man and the Wasp* (July 2018) provides more information about the main spoilered event.

In the mid-credits scene,

> Hope van Dyne (Wasp), Janet van Dyne, and Hank Pym disintegrate. Scott Lang (Ant-Man) survives,

but is

> trapped in the Quantum Realm.